On Footnotes Originating within an Mdframed Environment
Consider the code:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\textheight=3.75in
\let\thempfootnote\thefootnote % To get numerical footnotemark inside the box environment.

\usepackage{lipsum,enumitem,tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\newmdenv[usetwoside=false,shadow=true,leftmargin=3pt,backgroundcolor=black!10,shadowcolor=black,font=\sffamily,rightmargin=3pt,innerleftmargin=0.1cm]{shadedbox}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

This is a sentence.\footnote{Footnote 1.}\\[15pt]

\begin{shadedbox}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[\bfseries100] This is a sentence with a footnote appended.\footnote{I would like the footnote mark to be "2" (in this case) and have the adjoining footnote displayed outside the box in proper sequence.} \lipsum[13]
\end{enumerate}
\end{shadedbox}
\end{document}

which produces

QUESTION: How may I get a footnote mark inside the mdframed box to appear (in this case) as "2' and have the adjoining footnote appear outside of the box in the footnote list in proper sequence?
Thank you.

By using the package tablefootnote.sty this requirement is possible, but you have to tag the \footnote which comes inside mdframed environment to \tablefootnote and the MWE is:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\textheight=3.75in

%\let\thempfootnote\thefootnote % To get numerical footnotemark inside the box environment.

\usepackage{lipsum,enumitem,tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\newmdenv[usetwoside=false,shadow=true,leftmargin=3pt,backgroundcolor=black!10,shadowcolor=black,font=\sffamily,rightmargin=3pt,innerleftmargin=0.1cm]{shadedbox}

\usepackage{tablefootnote} 
\makeatletter 
\AfterEndEnvironment{mdframed}{%
 \tfn@tablefootnoteprintout% 
 \gdef\tfn@fnt{0}% 
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\thispagestyle{empty}

This is a sentence.\footnote{Footnote 1.}\\[15pt]

\begin{shadedbox}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[\bfseries100] This is a sentence with a footnote
appended.\tablefootnote{I would like the footnote mark to be "2" (in this case) and have the adjoining footnote displayed outside the box in proper sequence.} \lipsum[13]
\end{enumerate}
\end{shadedbox}
\end{document}



Many thanks for this fine answer.

I have since posted a question related to your answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/727508/coding-comment-footnotes-within-an-mdframed-environment. Thank you again.
