Coding Comment Footnotes within an Mdframed Environment
This question asks an extension of an answer given in On Footnotes Originating within an Mdframed Environment.
Consider the code:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\textheight=3.75in

\usepackage{lipsum,enumitem,tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\newmdenv[usetwoside=false,shadow=true,leftmargin=3pt,backgroundcolor=black!10,shadowcolor=black,font=\sffamily,rightmargin=3pt,innerleftmargin=0.1cm]{shadedbox}


\usepackage{tablefootnote} % <--- To get an ordinary footnote within mdframed box to appear outside the box in the list of footnotes.
\makeatletter 
\AfterEndEnvironment{mdframed}{%
 \tfn@tablefootnoteprintout% 
 \gdef\tfn@fnt{0}% 
}
\makeatother


% To produce a comment [unnumbered] footnote with \commentfootnote command.
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\commentfootnote}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{#1}%
  \def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}%
  \footnote{#2}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

This is a sentence with an ordinary footnote.\footnote{Footnote 1.}\\[15pt]


\begin{shadedbox}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[\bfseries100] This is a sentence with an ordinary footnote
appended within a box.\tablefootnote{I would like the footnote mark to be "2" (in this case) and have the adjoining footnote displayed outside the box in proper sequence.} 
\end{enumerate}
\end{shadedbox}


\vspace*{5pt}

\setcounter{footnote}{0} 
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}


\begin{shadedbox}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[\bfseries101] This is a sentence with a comment footnote
appended within a box.\tablefootnote{I would now like the footnote mark to be an asterisk and appear third in the footnote list.} 
\end{enumerate}
\end{shadedbox}


\vspace*{5pt}

\setcounter{footnote}{2} 
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}


This is another sentence with a comment footnote attached.\commentfootnote{$\dag$}{Comment footnotes are not numerically counted in the list of footnotes.} 


\vspace*{5pt}


This is the last sentence with an ordinary footnote.\footnote{Footnote 3.}
\end{document}

which produces:

The output is exactly what I want; however, the asterisked (comment) footnote in box 101 was accomplished in a rather laborious fashion as one can observe from the code.
QUESTION: How might I code the asterisked footnote in a more direct manner; e.g., perhaps along the lines of the \tablefootnote command (which I have so far not seen how to modify onto this purpose)?
Thank you.
